# HBase error: Server IPC version 8 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm using hbase-0.94.9, I tried to follow the introductions from HBase online book, but I got the error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException
```

Then I found on the Web that I had to set up Hadoop first, I used `start-dfs.sh` in Hadoop 2.0.5-alpha but now I get this error, when I try to run `start-hbase.sh`:

```
2013-07-09 17:27:40,706 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 8 cannot communicate with client version 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to use an HBase release that was built against Hadoop 1.0.x with hadoop 2.0.x. Either use an HBase release built against Hadoop 2.0.x or rebuild your HBase with `hadoop.profile` set to `2.0`

```
-Dhadoop.profile=2.0
```

If you need help on how to build HBase, you can visit this [link](http://hbase.apache.org/book/maven.build.commands.html#maven.build.hadoop).

HTH

Comment: Thanks! I changed to version 0.95.x of HBase and it worked.
I download hbase-0.94.9 because in the HBase Documentation it said it had support for Hadoop 2.x, but it isn't true :S

Comment: Pleasure. Happens sometimes.